# Rails 4 - where clauses for model with foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

I have the Notification Model. Each instance belongs to the User Model and to the Book model.

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :texto, :foreign_key => "text"
  belongs_to :usuario, :foreign_key => "user_related"
```

I also have some scopes defined in my Notification Model

```
scope :pending, ->(current_usuario_id) {
    joins(:texto).
    where("texto.usuario_id = ? AND notification.user_related != ?", current_usuario_id, current_usuario_id).
    where(:viewed => false)
  }
```

so I just get the current user unseen notifications. But I got this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "texto"
```

Any idea of how to do it right?

Comment: Maybe your table is named "textos" in plural, as rails usually does

Comment: Annoyingly enough, when I arrived this project had model names in Spanish. I change the `joins(:texto)` to `joins(:textos)` and the error now is `Association named 'textos' was not found on Notification; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: No, since you have "belongs_to :texto" in the same model, you need to use :texto. BUT the table name in the where clause has to be "textos". You can make this a certainty running this in rails console: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?("textos")

Comment: You're completely right. That did it. Do post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

joins() uses the symbol defined in the association, so `joins(:texto)` is correct.

On the other hand, in the "where" clause you MUST provide the table name as it exists in the database. Rails pluralizes table name after the model name at creation.

Running in console

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?("textos")
```

will make certain that the table name is "textos" and not "texto".